# Failed to login with access token on matrix server using simplematrixbotlib

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a bot based on a simplematrixbotlib library. When I use password authentication like this:

```
import simplematrixbotlib as botlib

creds = botlib.Creds(
    homeserver="https://example.org",
    username="username",
    password="password",
    session_stored_file="session.txt"
    )
bot = botlib.Bot(creds)
bot.run()
```

then everything works great! But when I want to implement authorization through an access token like this:

```
...
creds = botlib.Creds(
    homeserver="https://example.org",
    username="username",
    access_token="syt_c2...DTJ",
    session_stored_file="session.txt"
    )
...
```

then I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 127, in _verify_signature
    h.verify(data[-32:])
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py", line 72, in verify
    ctx.verify(signature)
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py", line 85, in verify
    raise InvalidSignature("Signature did not match digest.")
cryptography.exceptions.InvalidSignature: Signature did not match digest.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/main.py", line 498, in <module>
    bot.run()
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplematrixbotlib/bot.py", line 84, in run
    asyncio.run(self.main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplematrixbotlib/bot.py", line 43, in main
    self.creds.session_read_file()
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/simplematrixbotlib/auth.py", line 89, in session_read_file
    decrypted_session_data = fw.decrypt(
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fernet_wrapper/__init__.py", line 37, in decrypt
    data = str(f.decrypt(token))
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 88, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt_data(data, timestamp, time_info)
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 145, in _decrypt_data
    self._verify_signature(data)
  File "/home/shaman/simple-bot/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 129, in _verify_signature
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
```

I do everything as it is told in the documentation:
https://simple-matrix-bot-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#creating-an-instance-of-the-creds-class.
What am I doing wrong, why do I get an error?

I tried to change the access tokens, checked their relevance in the browser - it works there. But not in the code